# Best Practice: Multiple branches for different API versions or single branch

Tags: api, branch, versioning

We are still designing how the API versioning should be managed. As of now we have 2 options:

- All the versions in the same branch

  - Disadvantage: All versions might be using the same core libraries which might be affected by a new commit. There is no code freeze on the older versions.
- Different branches for each version

  - Disadvantage: Manging lot of branches might be a nightmare when it comes to maintanence

Is there any other option to do it in a better way or should I have to proceed with one of the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest separate release branches for each API. You can do bug fixes to old versions off of the release branches.

You shouldn't have lots of versions of your API. If this is a web API, then non-breaking changes don't need a new version. If this is a programming language API, then each major release should be a branch, with minor releases as tags or sub-branches off of the release.